# How can I make only table content scrollable, while keeping everything else inside the div stationery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to create a page to display my CSV data neatly. The table being used to display the CSV data is inside a flexbox container div. Currently, the max height of the container is set to `95vh`, and once the table starts the exceeds the height, it makes the entire div container scrollable.

However, I am only looking to make the table data itself scrollable (i.e., `<tbody>`), not the entire container. This effectively means I want to keep my `<h2>` header and `<thead>` header, inside the `<div>` container, **stationery** while making the table scrollable if it exceeds the max height of the container.

I have looked at several past Stack Overflow posts to make only the table content scrollable, and attempted CSS methods such as `display: block` and `position: sticky`, but it does not achieve the desired effect I intend for.

If there is a duplicate post to mine (*that exactly solves my issue*), please link me to it, as I have extensively searched for duplicates. And I would like to solve this issue using pure HTML/CSS/JS or with the help of external scripts.

***My code*** (*you can also tinker with my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spenpal/gm0xv4t5/2/)*)

```js
// Define CSV data here
const testData = `Value1A,Value1B,Value1C
Value2A,Value2B,Value2C
Value3A,Value3B,Value3C
Value4A,Value4B,Value4C
Value5A,Value5B,Value5C
Value6A,Value6B,Value6C
Value7A,Value7B,Value7C
Value8A,Value8B,Value8C
Value9A,Value9B,Value9C
Value10A,Value10B,Value10C
Value11A,Value11B,Value11C
Value12A,Value12B,Value12C
Value13A,Value13B,Value13C
Value14A,Value14B,Value14C
Value15A,Value15B,Value15C`;

// Split the CSV data
let rows = testData.split("\n");

// Add table tags to each row and cell
let table = "";
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  const columns = row.split(/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))/);
  table += `<tr>`;

  // Iterate over each column
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    table += "<td>" + column.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1") + "</td>";
  });

  table += "</tr>";
});

// Update the table body
const tbody = document.querySelector("#csv-table tbody");
tbody.innerHTML = table;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
  background-color: #d9efa1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.csv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.csv h2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  color: #f6b40e;
}

.csv table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.csv table thead th {
  background-color: #f6b40e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: left;
}

.csv table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
}

.csv table tbody td {
  padding: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSV</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="csv">
      <h2>CSV</h2>
      <table id="csv-table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Dynamically generated rows will be added here -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by [Wongjn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76643735/how-to-make-only-table-content-scrollable-while-keeping-everything-else-inside/#76644585): position sticky can help.

But you can also wrap your `<table>` in a `<div>` with a max-height and overflow auto and give your `<thead>` a **sticky** position like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.table-wrp {
  max-height:70vh;
  overflow:auto;
}


thead{
  position:sticky;
  top:0
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
  background-color: #d9efa1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.csv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  //max-height: 95vh;
  //overflow: auto;
}

.csv h2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  color: #f6b40e;
}

.csv table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.csv table thead th {
  background-color: #f6b40e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: left;
}

.csv table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
}

.csv table tbody td {
  padding: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="csv">
    <h2>CSV</h2>
    <div class="table-wrp">
    <table id="csv-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
          <th>C</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Value1A</td>
          <td>Value1B</td>
          <td>Value1C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value2A</td>
          <td>Value2B</td>
          <td>Value2C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value3A</td>
          <td>Value3B</td>
          <td>Value3C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value4A</td>
          <td>Value4B</td>
          <td>Value4C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value5A</td>
          <td>Value5B</td>
          <td>Value5C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value6A</td>
          <td>Value6B</td>
          <td>Value6C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value7A</td>
          <td>Value7B</td>
          <td>Value7C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value8A</td>
          <td>Value8B</td>
          <td>Value8C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value9A</td>
          <td>Value9B</td>
          <td>Value9C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value10A</td>
          <td>Value10B</td>
          <td>Value10C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value11A</td>
          <td>Value11B</td>
          <td>Value11C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value12A</td>
          <td>Value12B</td>
          <td>Value12C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value13A</td>
          <td>Value13B</td>
          <td>Value13C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value14A</td>
          <td>Value14B</td>
          <td>Value14C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Value15A</td>
          <td>Value15B</td>
          <td>Value15C</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We need this additional wrap because a **sticky parent element with overflow auto or scroll will disable the sticky behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

We add selectors for `tbody`, `thead tr` and `th, td` and use `display: block`.

```js
// Define CSV data here
const testData = `Value1A,Value1B,Value1C
Value2A,Value2B,Value2C
Value3A,Value3B,Value3C
Value4A,Value4B,Value4C
Value5A,Value5B,Value5C
Value6A,Value6B,Value6C
Value7A,Value7B,Value7C
Value8A,Value8B,Value8C
Value9A,Value9B,Value9C
Value10A,Value10B,Value10C
Value11A,Value11B,Value11C
Value12A,Value12B,Value12C
Value13A,Value13B,Value13C
Value14A,Value14B,Value14C
Value15A,Value15B,Value15C`;

// Split the CSV data
let rows = testData.split("\n");

// Add table tags to each row and cell
let table = "";
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  const columns = row.split(/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))/);
  table += `<tr>`;

  // Iterate over each column
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    table += "<td>" + column.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1") + "</td>";
  });

  table += "</tr>";
});

// Update the table body
const tbody = document.querySelector("#csv-table tbody");
tbody.innerHTML = table;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
  background-color: #d9efa1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.csv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.csv h2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  color: #f6b40e;
}

.csv table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.csv th,
.csv td {
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: left;
   width: 400px;
 }


.csv table thead th {
  background-color: #f6b40e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: left;
}

.csv thead tr {
    display: block;
}

.csv table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
}

.csv table tbody td {
  padding: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.csv tbody {
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>CSV</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="csv">
        <h2>CSV</h2>
        <table id="csv-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>A</th>
              <th>B</th>
              <th>C</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!-- Dynamically generated rows will be added here -->
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `position: sticky` with an appropriate `top` value. You may also wish to consider having some sort of background color to prevent the scrolled values showing above the table header.

```js
// Define CSV data here
const testData = `Value1A,Value1B,Value1C
Value2A,Value2B,Value2C
Value3A,Value3B,Value3C
Value4A,Value4B,Value4C
Value5A,Value5B,Value5C
Value6A,Value6B,Value6C
Value7A,Value7B,Value7C
Value8A,Value8B,Value8C
Value9A,Value9B,Value9C
Value10A,Value10B,Value10C
Value11A,Value11B,Value11C
Value12A,Value12B,Value12C
Value13A,Value13B,Value13C
Value14A,Value14B,Value14C
Value15A,Value15B,Value15C`;

// Split the CSV data
let rows = testData.split("\n");

// Add table tags to each row and cell
let table = "";
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  const columns = row.split(/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))/);
  table += `<tr>`;

  // Iterate over each column
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    table += "<td>" + column.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1") + "</td>";
  });

  table += "</tr>";
});

// Update the table body
const tbody = document.querySelector("#csv-table tbody");
tbody.innerHTML = table;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
  background-color: #d9efa1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.csv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.csv h2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  color: #f6b40e;
}

.csv table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.csv table thead th {
  background-color: #f6b40e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: left;
}

.csv table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
}

.csv table tbody td {
  padding: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSV</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="csv">
      <h2 style="position: sticky; top: calc(min(1024px, 100vw) * 0.0084)">CSV</h2>
      <table id="csv-table">
        <thead style="position: sticky; top: calc((min(1024px, 100vw) * 0.0336) + 1.75em)">
          <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Dynamically generated rows will be added here -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

To explain the `top` values I've used here:

`calc(min(1024px, 100vw) * 0.0084)` is derived from `margin-top: 1%` is `1%` of the **width** of the containing box. However, the percentage for `top` uses the **height** so we cannot apply `top: 1%`, so instead, we need to calculate what `margin-top: 1%` is:

- `min(1024px, 100vw)` is the `.container`'s width, which is implicitly 100% of the viewport, `100vw` up to its `max-width: 1024px`, the `1024px`.
- The `0.0084` is derived from:

  - There is left and right `padding` of `.container` of `5%` each, that is `0.05` each side.
  - There is left and right `padding` of `.csv` of `3%` each, that is `0.03` each side.
  - There is the `1%` `margin-top` itself, equal to `0.01`.
  - So the multiplicative factor is:

    ```
    (1 - (0.05 × 2) - (0.03 × 2)) × 0.01 = 0.84 × 0.01 = 0.0084
    ```

For `calc((min(1024px, 100vw) * 0.0336) + 1.75em)`, it is mostly the same:

- `min(1024px, 100vw)` is the `.container`'s width, which is implicitly 100% of the viewport, `100vw` up to its `max-width: 1024px`, the `1024px`.
- The `0.0084` is derived from:

  - There is left and right `padding` of `.container` of `5%` each, that is `0.05` each side.
  - There is left and right `padding` of `.csv` of `3%` each, that is `0.03` each side.
  - There is the `1%` `margin-top` of the `<h2>`, equal to `0.01`.
  - There is the `3%` `margin-bottom` of the `<h2>`, equal to `0.03`.
  - So the multiplicative factor is:

    ```
    (1 - (0.05 × 2) - (0.03 × 2)) × 0.04 = 0.84 × 0.04 = 0.0336
    ```
- `1.75em` comes from the `line-height` of the `<h2>` text.

If you want to be super accurate, we'd need to use JavaScript. This is because non-overlay scrollbars can give us slightly different values, and we do not have the necessary values in CSS alone to calculate it properly.

```js
// Define CSV data here
const testData = `Value1A,Value1B,Value1C
Value2A,Value2B,Value2C
Value3A,Value3B,Value3C
Value4A,Value4B,Value4C
Value5A,Value5B,Value5C
Value6A,Value6B,Value6C
Value7A,Value7B,Value7C
Value8A,Value8B,Value8C
Value9A,Value9B,Value9C
Value10A,Value10B,Value10C
Value11A,Value11B,Value11C
Value12A,Value12B,Value12C
Value13A,Value13B,Value13C
Value14A,Value14B,Value14C
Value15A,Value15B,Value15C`;

// Split the CSV data
let rows = testData.split("\n");

// Add table tags to each row and cell
let table = "";
rows.forEach(function(row) {
  const columns = row.split(/,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))/);
  table += `<tr>`;

  // Iterate over each column
  columns.forEach(function(column) {
    table += "<td>" + column.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, "$1") + "</td>";
  });

  table += "</tr>";
});

// Update the table body
const tbody = document.querySelector("#csv-table tbody");
tbody.innerHTML = table;

const tableElement = document.getElementById('csv-table');
const { width } = tableElement.getBoundingClientRect();

document
  .querySelector('.csv')
  .style.setProperty('--w', `${width}px`);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
  background-color: #d9efa1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.csv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.csv h2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  color: #f6b40e;
}

.csv table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.csv table thead th {
  background-color: #f6b40e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: left;
}

.csv table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
}

.csv table tbody td {
  padding: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>CSV</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="csv">
      <h2 style="position: sticky; top: calc(var(--w) * 0.01)">CSV</h2>
      <table id="csv-table">
        <thead style="position: sticky; top: calc((var(--w) * 0.04) + 1.75em)">
          <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Dynamically generated rows will be added here -->
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would I go about hiding the content above the table header?

Comment: As stated in the answer, you could have "some sort of background color to prevent the scrolled values showing above the table header."

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to add properties in tbody instead of table.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
  background-color: #d9efa1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5%;
}

.csv {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  max-height: 95vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

.csv h2 {
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  color: #f6b40e;
}

.csv table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.csv table thead th {
  background-color: #f6b40e;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 3%;
  text-align: left;
}


.csv table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #F3F2F1;
}

.csv table tbody td {
  padding: 3%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.csv table tbody {
  display:block;
  max-height:50vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

thead, tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To make only the table content scrollable while keeping everything else inside a div stationary, you can achieve this by applying CSS styles to the container div. Here's an example:

HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header Content</div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <!-- Table content -->
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS styles:

```
.container {
  /* Set a fixed height for the container */
  height: 400px;
  /* Set the desired styles for the container */
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  /* Set the styles for the header */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

.table-wrapper {
  /* Set the styles for the table wrapper */
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  /* Set the desired styles for the table wrapper */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

.table-wrapper table {
  /* Set the styles for the table */
  width: 100%;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}

.footer {
  /* Set the styles for the footer */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  /* Additional styles as needed */
}
```

In this example, the .container div acts as the main container with a fixed height. The .header and .footer divs are placed at the top and bottom respectively, while the .table-wrapper div wraps the table and is set to be scrollable using the overflow-y: scroll; property. Adjust the height of the .table-wrapper div based on the available space within the container.

By applying these styles, the table content will be scrollable within the .table-wrapper div, while the header and footer will remain stationary.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT